# I wanted to print the first set bit from right side, What is the error in this coding?

Tags: java

There is some problem in for loop. please write the right code

```
        int n = scan.nextInt(); //Entered integer number
        String y=Integer.toBinaryString(n);  //converted to binary string
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(n));
        int r = y.length();
        for(int j=r-1; j>=0; j--)
        {
            if(y.charAt(j)=='1') {
            int z = j+1;
            System.out.println("j is "+z);
            break; }
        }
```

Comment: do you mean the position of the first set bit from right hand side?

Comment: What are you trying to do in the loop?

Comment: Please read [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Your program currently prints the position of the first set bit traversing from right but the position is marked from left hand side.

To get the position relatively from right hand side, you can change to -

```
int r = y.length();
for (int j = r - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
    if (y.charAt(j) == '1') {
        System.out.println("The first set bit position from right is - " + (r-j));
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do. But here is how to get the position of the first 1 from the left and from the right

```
package foo;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class mapping {

    public mapping() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Insert num: ");
        int n = scan.nextInt(); //Entered integer number
        String y=Integer.toBinaryString(n);  //converted to binary string
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(n));
        int r = y.length();
        for(int j=0; j < r; j++)
        {
            if(y.charAt(j)=='1') 
            {
            int z = j+1;
            System.out.println("First 1 from the right is in position: " + z);
            break; 
            }
        }
        for(int j = r - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            if(y.charAt(j)=='1') 
            {
            int z = j+1;
            System.out.println("First 1 from the left is in position: " + z);
            break; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```